# $httpBackend not stubbing the request/response?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test my `$scope.init(id)` function. In this function I make a request to my API that returns an array of objects, so I want to stub it out with a preset response.

This is my failing test:

```
describe('mysite', function() {
  var scope, MensDetailCtrl, $httpBackend;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('mysite');
  });

  describe('MensDetailCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $injector) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();

      $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
      $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/products/1').respond({name: 'product_name'});

      MensDetailCtrl = $controller('MensDetailCtrl', {
        '$scope': scope
      });
    }));


    describe('init(id)', function() {
      it('sets scope.product', function() {
        scope.init(1);
        console.log(scope.product.name); // HERE: prints undefined
        expect(scope.product).toBeDefined();
      });


    });


  });

});
```

And this is my controller:

```
app.controller('MensDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', '$controller', 'Product', function($scope, $resource, $controller, Product) {
  $controller('ProductsDetailCtrl', {$scope: $scope});


  $scope.init = function(id)
  {
    console.log("zzzzz"); // this is printed
    $scope.product = Product.get({productId: id}, function(data) {
      console.log("here!!!"); // this is not printed
    });

  }
   ...

}]);
```

And my factory:

```
app.factory('Product', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/products/:productId", {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
  });
}]);
```

Didn't I already stub it out with this `$httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/products/1').respond({name: 'product_name'});`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$httpBackend.flush()`. This is how we work around the asynchronous nature of HTTP requests in tests.

```
describe('init(id)', function() {
  it('sets scope.product', function() {
    scope.init(1);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    console.log(scope.product.name); // HERE: prints undefined
    expect(scope.product).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Also, for this sort of test I like to use `httpBackend.expectGET('/api/products/1').respond(...)`. The reason is that your test is expecting this HTTP request, and will fail if it's not made. When it does fail, it will be much more clear why in the error message.

**Edit**

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) gives a good explanation of when to use "when" versus "expect" methods.
It's also a good idea to throw in calls to `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()`, `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest()` (perhaps in an `afterEach()` block).

Comment: Thanks! so are you saying I should have 2 expectations in that spec? (`expect(scope.product).toBeDefined();` and `httpBackend.expectGET('/api/products/1').respond(...)` ?

Comment: Yes, I like verifying both things have occurred. It might seem trivial in this case, because you know that for `scope.product` to be defined that the HTTP request had to have been made. But I also look at the tests as "documentation" about what the function is supposed to be doing.